# What is the purposes symbol @ in PHP $variable at blade laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

How do you do ?

I would like to ask about symbol @ in PHP $variable in blade laravel 5. This is the code that I get, but unfortunately the previous programmer was is lost.

[image]

Please note at this -> {{ old('title_id', @$result->title_id) }}.

Why using @ ? and what is different with {{ old('title_id', $result->title_id) }} without @.

Thank you very much

Comment: Hello, it is used to suppress errors and warnings.

Comment: okay, but what is the different between @$result->title_id and $result->title_id, without @ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@` is used as error control operator at php. Php will not throw any error generated from the exception.

`{{ old('title_id', @$result->title_id) }}`.
The purpose to use the `@` symbol here is to **prevent the program from throw exception** like "try to call title_id from an empty object". Instead it goes with define the variable with null value. It sometimes usefull when you want to do the edit / create on the same blade file.

If you dont use @ symbol, you must handle if the variable is empty or not first and you ended up with code like

```
{{ old('title_id', $result ? $result->title_id : '') }}
```

You can read more detail at [php documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).